# What is required to unlock the Green Cities DLC climate research station?

Tags: cities-skylines

The hover hint says you need 5000 squares of farming specialization built to unlock the a *Green Cities* DLC **Climate Research Station (CRS)**, but I don’t see the term squares used in relation to the industry Tools and info views. 
[image: screenshot of CRS info]

For example, the farm-info tab lists a farm’s size in terms of cells, but as the screenshot below shows I have >8700 cells in just one farm (specialized industry zone from the Industries DLC) yet the CRS remains locked.

So to what is the hover hint referring?

[image: screensot of farm-info tab]

Answer (score 1):

The description isn’t clear, but any Industry DLC farm buildings and fields do not count toward the requirements.  You would actually need 5000 tiles of zoned farming specialization!  It seems you already have 607 of the 5000 farming squares requirement, so you should already have designated farming districts.

Just as a refresher for others who might see this answer, you can designate farming districts by accessing the districts tab, painting a district over an area you wish to be farmland, and designating that district as farming industry. Farms should start popping up and growing, and you should see the squares count requirements go up!